# Setting up GDB with DDD for OS-161

Tags: gdb, ddd-debugger, os161

I'm setting up gdb for debugging OS-161 and I'm planning to use DDD as a visual front-end. I'm following instructions from the official CS-161 course page: http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~cs161/resources/eclipse.html (scroll down to DDD).

After switching to my kern/compile/DUMBVM where I built the kernel I launch DDD with `ddd -debugger mips-harvard-os161-gdb --gdb kernel` (because the OS161 kernel is installed as kernel). When I do this, DDD opens up one of the source files of my OS tree.

Then after launching sys161 with a debugging mode `sys161 -w kernel`, I type `target remote unix:os161/root/.sockets/gdb` in DDD which gives me the following error: `unix:os161/root/.sockets/gdb: No such file or directory`

What could be causing this error? I can successfully set up gdb without DDD using the target remote comman in my .gdbinit so I know that the gdb file within the .sockets directory exists and works. One thing I'm doubtful about is why the initial command launching ddd opens up a specific source file (it's the same every time), could this be linked?

It's be great especially if anyone who's had experience with OS161 knows how to set up gdb with a GUI front-end (doesn't have to be DDD strictly), to ease debugging (I don't wanna use vim :/).

Btw I'm using Debian Jessie if that helps.

Comment: Try using the full pathname, such as `unix:/home/cloudy/os161/root/.sockets/gdb`

Comment: I tried unix:/$HOME/os161/root/.sockets/gdb which is equivalent right?

Comment: gdb rarely expands environment variables. Can you try using the full pathname? Just copy and output of the shell command `find ~ -name gdb -type s`

Comment: Yep, works like a charm! Thanks a ton man :D :)